# Normal map baking doing something wrong

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, baking, normal-map

I've been wondering around in several forums since yesterday trying to fix my issue, with no succes.

I am modeling a golem for a project and I'm having some normal baking problems with it.

I first did the low poly one (not a workflow I'm used to). Then, when the result was good enough, I rigged it, duplicated it and subdivided it to make some stone details via a normal map. But when I try to bake normals from the high poly to the low poly one the normal map seems wrong.

[image: Golem Normal Map]

[image: Golem Normal Map]

The two golems are pretty much the same, I did a simple subdivide to make sure I don't have to create many holding edges to keep the mesh straight and the only thing I changed are the sculpt you see in the down left corner. These changes are okay, but any ideas why I can see all of these edges? I repeat that only one thing has changed in the mesh. For those that are wondering, yes, I tried brute forcing the distance and bias parameters. But in order to see the changes I kind of must keep these where they are.

I would like to know if any one of you guys have any ideas about why is that hapenning and if you got any ideas for fixing it.

For information, i'm using the Blender Render and I stacked one mesh to another of course.

[image]

Comment: *" the sculpt you see in the down left corner"* corner of what? Did you include that screenshot? What are those edges you can see? Did you expect not seeing them? Are you selecting highpoly first when baking? Distance should be increased to allow rays to be casted from the highpoly to lowpoly and include differences into the map. Note also to include screenshots here using built-in tool of this site.

Comment: Oh, you can't see the image? I'm sorry for that, i can personally see it, i thought i did it the right way, let me post it again, brb :)
Of course i selected the high poly first and as you will see when i'll figure a way to upload the image right that increasing the ray distance makes it only worse ^^

Comment: I saw only one image with the normal map which didn't really explain where are edges you didn't expect. To include images here see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: I posted the link, my golems are both the same pretty much, the only difference between them is one is low and the other is high poly and even though they look the same the normals show edges that shouldn't be there. If you want i can link you the blend file for a better understanding

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3909" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3909/)

This is the .blend file for you to understand the problem i've got. I thought i understood how normal works but i just can't figure out why the normal bake shows edges that are not different from a mesh to another

Comment: Have a look at my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/115411/low-poly-mesh-oddly-sharp-edges-on-normal-map-where-it-is-supposed-to-be-smooth/115440#115440 . Also I would suggest being more specific. Name your problems instead of assuming they are obvious, also make sure you describe the relevant context if you are talking about something.

Answer (score 1):

just smooth your low poly mesh before baking:

Edit mode -> 'A' to select everything -> 'T' for tools sidebar -> Go to 'shading/UVs' in the sidepanel -> Under faces press 'smooth'

Don't worry about edges being soft when you bake a normal map onto it, it will give it it's sharp look back when the normal map is applied :)